# RxJava2 - How to write a custom logic of grouping items?

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java2

All of the examples I have read, talks about having a separate boundary condition in **buffer** and **window** 
I would want to have a custom boundary condition based on the items being emitted.
For example:

Read items from a list, group them till the sum is less than 100. 
I have a list -

```
[10, 30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 50, 30, 80]
```

Keep on grouping the items till their sum is less than 100 and then emit. Output of above list shall be:

```
[10, 30, 40]
[50, 20, 30]
[50, 30]
[80]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: See the RxJava 2 Extensions about [bufferWhile](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersbufferwhile) and 2 other splitting strategies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As proposed by akarnokd, you can use [`bufferWhile`](https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Extensions#flowabletransformersbufferwhile) from RxJava2 Extensions.

To have a condition on sum, you can use a custom `Predicate`:

```
Flowable.just(10, 30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 50, 30, 80)
        .compose(FlowableTransformers.bufferWhile(new Predicate<Integer>() {
            private int sum = 0;

            @Override
            public boolean test(Integer next) {
                if (sum + next > 100) {
                    sum = next;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    sum += next;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

The output is exactly the expected:

```
[10, 30, 40]
[50, 20, 30]
[50, 30]
[80]
```